# Simplest way to get a polygon from Illustrator to Java?

Tags: java, polygon

What's the simplest way to get a polygon (doesn't need curves etc, just an array of points) from Illustrator (or any other vector graphics program, for that matter) into a Java Polygon object?

I'm not really eager to implement a very heavy SVG class, my app needs to be as light-weight as possible.

I know it's a very wide question, but so may your answers be. Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Before you try to implement an SVG library, have you looked to see if there is already one out there you could use?

Comment: Most of them are really overly extensive for my purpose - I'm currently looking into importing SVG files myself, though

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try "FXG Converter (webstart)" (http://idisk.mac.com/han.solo-Public/fxgconverter.jnlp) from http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/.